# Gack when using aura:iteration and indexVar?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have two nearly identical lists that will bind to separate values, so I was trying to use some sort of list that would allow me to avoid creating a component. Here's the code that I've tried:

```
<aura:application>
    <aura:attribute name="id" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute access="private" name="headers" type="String[]" default="['On','Off']" />
    
    <aura:iteration indexVar="sectIdx" items="{!v.headers}" var="header">
    
    </aura:iteration>
    
</aura:application>
```

At this point, I get an internal server error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
> Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application. An internal
> server error has occurred
>
> Error ID: 1187952221-8254 (-246848975)

Are we supposed to be able to do this? If not, is there another way to do this so that I can avoid creating a custom component just to create the nearly identical lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of Gack is because the body for the aura app is not created until you have added valid HTML markup .

Aura Iteration does not form the body for the component and hence is the error .There are few tags like that does this odd behaviour .aura:renderif was another one.

I tried below and it should just work

```
<aura:application>
 <aura:attribute name="id" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute  name="headers" type="String[]" default="['On','Off']" />

<aura:iteration indexVar="sectIdx" items="{!v.headers}" var="header">
  <h1></h1>
</aura:iteration>
```

If you want to print this list then below is the code

```
<aura:application>
 <aura:attribute name="id" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute  name="headers" type="String[]" default="['On','Off']" />

<aura:iteration indexVar="sectIdx" items="{!v.headers}" var="header">
  <h1>{!header}</h1>
</aura:iteration>
```

Also note that if you make an attribute private it wont be visible to v.body of the component formed .This seemed odd to me as I would expect it to be visible within same namespace .May be the behaviour is it is visible only to the controller JS and helper .

Comment: Wow. That's definitely odd. So my approach should work okay, it just happened to fail because I hadn't written enough code. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if we can use something like headers[sectIdx]? I couldn't find anything on that either.

Comment: Precisely because aura:iteration tag does not create body  .If you would have used any other tag it would have worked

Comment: Dynamic reference is not yet supported I believe but give a shot since things are changing rapidly with component framework

Comment: `{!v.headers[v.sectIdx]}` doesn't seem to work, nor anything else I do. Eventually, I'd like to be able to iterate over `v.sections[v.sectIdx]`, where the sections are populated from queries.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll just use a component. At least I know I'm not going crazy. Thanks, again, Mohith!

Comment: Nps :) .Good luck :)

Comment: PS: The error you got you would have got same with even component if only aura: iteration was present

Comment: Thanks, Mohith, I'll try and work from there. I just think this is the most oddly gack I've ever seen.